# Car wont start, starter will click, dome lights and headlights are dim

Tags: battery, ignition, starter

Ive got an 08 Impala that was running just fine two days ago. Yesterday I went to get in to go to work and it wouldnt turn over. The interior lights and headlights a very dim. I tried to jump it, and that didnt work. I had the battery tested, and it tested at 99%. I replaced the starter and have the same issue? What else should i be looking at?

Comment: If it was the guy who "tested the battery" who recommended changing the starter, go elsewhere. If the lights are all dim, that isn't likely to be the fault of the starter motor.

Comment: By “jump it” do you mean you connected another battery via jump leads?  How long did you leave the jump leads connected before trying to start the car?  More than 10 minutes?

Comment: What you are describing is a classic dead battery, replacing your starter is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have an electrical SUPPLY problem and it's obvious that the starter is not the issue.

1. Have the battery LOAD TESTED.  If that passes then there is another issue.
2. Check your battery cables.  They should be clean and firmly connected without corrosion at the terminals.  CHECK BOTH ENDS!
3. Some vehicles have a "fusible link" in the (+) cable, check that or have it checked.
4. The (+) lead usually goes to a terminal block of some sort.  Make sure that is properly connected, clean, and corrosion free.
5. The (-) lead usually connects to the frame or engine.  Check that connection.